# Put the values of the table to one row in multiple columns mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like this:

post_image

```
image_id| image_name    | post_id  
1       | hallo.jpg     | 1  
2       | morning.jpg   | 1  
3       | sun.jpg       | 2
4       | star.jpg      | 3
```

post_table

```
post_id | post_text     
1       | hallo     
2       | morning all   
3       | sunlight       
4       | my night
```

the expected result is

```
post_text   | image_1   | image_2     | image_3 | image_4 | count_image
hallo       | hallo.jpg | morning.jpg | null    | null    | 2
morning all | sun.jpg   | null        | null    | null    | 1  
sunlight    | star.jpg  | null        | null    | null    | 1  
my night    | null      | null        | null    | null    | 0
```

can someone help me, how to create that output using query?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the values in separate columns can be tricky.  Perhaps a delimited string will suffice:

```
select p.post_id, p.post_text,
       group_concat(image_name) as images,
       count(i.post_id) as num_images
from post_table p left join
     post_image i
     on p.post_id = i.post_id
group by p.post_id, p.post_text;
```